# Compile CoffeeScript on Save?

Tags: javascript, node.js, textmate, coffeescript

Is there anyway to easily compile CoffeeScript on save? I'm using TextMate or Sublime Text 2.

Comment: CoffeeScript compiler setup for WebStorm
http://zsitro.com/coffeescript-compiler-setup-for-webstorm/

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Coffeescript has a 'watch' feature.  You could set up, as a semi-permanent process:

```
coffee –wc -o media/js/ src/coffee/*.coffee
```

And for every file with an extension ".coffee", the corresponding compiled ".js" file will be put into the target directory every time you save.

That said, I use a makefile and a fabfile, because my HTML is HAML, my CSS is LessCSS, and my development directory is not my test path, so I needed something smart enough to "build and deploy."

If your machine supports inotify, you could use inotifywait to watch your entire work path, and call Make as needed.  But at that point, you're into hard-core geekery.

Comment: Elf's answer is correct. There's also Jitter, a small project of mine that adds a few extra features (like Growl notifications when there are compilation errors): http://github.com/TrevorBurnham/jitter

Comment: If you are using the HAML, SASS/Compass and CoffeeScript combo you might as well give [StaticMatic 2](https://github.com/mindeavor/staticmatic2) a try.

Comment: Thanks this got me pointed in the right direction. I used the command `coffee -c -o dirToBuildTo --watch dirToBuildFrom` works great.

Comment: I wrote this, which does the trick for coffeescript and less.
https://bitbucket.org/poulejapon/tumbler/downloads

Answer (score 19):

You can also accomplish this without the command line:

1. [Add a build process to Sublime Text](http://prototypef.tumblr.com/post/7211089141/adding-extra-coffeescript-goodies-to-sublime-text-2).
2. Make sure that `Save All on Build` is selected in the `Tools` menu.
3. Use ⌘B instead of ⌘S when saving.

So instead of compiling on save, you're saving on compile.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward solution with Sublime, is to install the Sublime package called Better Coffeescript (preferences --> package control --> install package...), and then make sure that its configuration includes `"compileOnSave": true` (preferences --> package settings --> Better Coffeescript...). Then restart Sublime.

For Sublime, anything else is not enough or too much extra components. Just came here after upgrading to Sublime 3, and it works like charm for Sublime 3 (as it did for Sublime 2, I just forgot about it at first).

Answer (score 2):

Well `coffee --watch` has 2 major flaws:

- New files created after command has been issued aren't being watched
- Requires manual initiation so there can be a chance you forget to do it, which doesn't sound more brilliant than forget to compile before you `git commit` it

The solution I came up with is a rather simple Bash script that takes `coffee --watch` a few steps further which will allow your working directory tree to be watched ever since system login, and automatically get compiled into JavaScript on each file save/change
or new file creation:

http://blog.gantrithor.com/post/11609373640/carefree-coffeescript-auto-compiler

There may be more elegant way to do this, but this implementation works great =)

Comment: Try `coffee -wc -o . .` which will compile all old and new .coffee files. It's only when you do: `coffee -wc -o . ./*.coffee` that your first "flaw" appears.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want bundling, buildr offers watching and bundling too: https://github.com/balupton/buildr.npm

> The (Java|Coffee)Script and (CSS|Less) (Builder|Bundler|Packer|Minifier|Merger|Checker)

Answer (score 1):

```
gem install stasis
stasis -d
```

The best solution I have found compared with all other static compilation tools like StaticMatic, Middleman, etc.

Very flexible and configurable and does not rely on any preset folder structure. Just add `controller.rb` and write some Ruby. Lots of helpers for doing clever things before/after compilation.

https://github.com/winton/stasis

Answer (score 0):

I like codekit :) Simple and effective way to compile coffeescript, sass, less, haml, and more, with lots of niceties. http://incident57.com/codekit/