# How to watch and recompile coffee scripts as they change?

Tags: coffeescript

Some time ago I used to do

```
coffee --bare --output . --watch --compile .
```

This watches the `.coffee` files in the current dir and recompiles them as they change.

Now, using 1.2.0 of coffeescript this does not seem to work any more. I'm presented with an error:

```
File not found: --watch.coffee
```

and the [usage documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#usage) for `coffee` seems rather light.

Comment: Hmm... `--compile --output . .` works, but putting `--output .` in between other flags doesn't. This sounds like a regression to me. It's worth reporting it on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd skip the `--output .`, as it seems to be unnecessary if you're already in the same directory, and go straight with

```
coffee -bcw *.coffee
```

Otherwise, this is a duplicate of [Compile CoffeeScript on Save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286366/compile-coffeescript-on-save/6286510#6286510)

Answer (score 3):

BTW, you can also go:

```
coffee -bcw .
```

which will not only save a few keystrokes, but also scan subdirectories to compile .coffee files.